# How to remove duplicates from a list then sort by most frequent

Tags: scala

I have a list with assorted keywords that may repeat. I need to generate a list with distinct keywords but sorted by the frequency of which they appeared on the original list.

How would be the idiomatic Scala for that? Here is a working but ugly implementation:

```
val keys = List("c","a","b","b","a","a")
keys.groupBy(p => p).toList.sortWith( (a,b) => a._2.size > b._2.size ).map(_._1)
// List("a","b","c")
```

Comment: well, it feels like that there is function more appropriate for that, which I missing, like fold or aggregate, that would be used to make it clearer.

Comment: Would it be useful to have a variant of groupBy where you could pass a a function to say how to merge/fold the next value into the grouped keys? There are any number of questions/answers here where it's groupBy + map over it to bodge the value into the desired result...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shorter version:

```
keys.distinct.sortBy(keys count _.==).reverse
```

That is not particular efficient, however. The `groupBy` version ought to perform better, though it can be improved:

```
keys.groupBy(identity).toSeq.sortBy(_._2.size).map(_._1)
```

One can also get rid of the `reverse` in the first version by declaring an `Ordering`:

```
val ord = Ordering by (keys count (_: String).==)
keys.distinct.sorted(ord.reverse)
```

Note that `reverse` in this version just produces a new `Ordering` that works in the opposite manner of the original. This version also suggests a way to get better performance:

```
val freq = collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, Int] withDefaultValue 0
keys foreach (k => freq(k) += 1)
val ord = Ordering by freq
keys.distinct.sorted(ord.reverse)
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with that implementation that comments can't fix!
Seriously, break it down a bit and describe what & why you're taking each step.

Not as "concise" perhaps, but the purpose of concise code in scala *is* to make code more readable.  When concise code is not clear it's time to back up, break up (introduce well named local variables), and comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take, don't know if it's less "ugly":

```
scala> keys.groupBy(p => p).values.toList.sortBy(_.size).reverse.map(_.head)
res39: List[String] = List(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

fold version:

```
val keys = List("c","a","b","b","a","a")

val keysCounts =
    (Map.empty[String, Int] /: keys) { case (counts, k) =>
        counts updated (k, (counts getOrElse (k, 0)) + 1)
    }

keysCounts.toList sortBy { case (_, count) => -count } map { case (w, _) => w }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
keys.distinct.sorted
```

Newbie didn't read the question carefully. Let me try again:

```
keys.foldLeft (Map[String,Int]()) { (counts, elem) => counts + (elem -> (counts.getOrElse(elem, 0) - 1))}
    .toList.sortBy(_._2).map(_._1)
```

Could use a mutable Map if you prefer. Negative frequency counts are stored in the map. If that bothers you, you can make them positive and negate the sortBy argument.

Comment: that would sort the strings alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps,

```
val mapCount = keys.map(x => (x,keys.count(_ == x))).distinct
// mapCount  : List[(java.lang.String, Int)] = List((c,1), (a,3), (b,2))

val sortedList = mapCount.sortWith(_._2 > _._2).map(_._1)
// sortedList  : List[java.lang.String] = List(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little change from @Daniel 's 4th version, may have a better performance:

```
scala> def sortByFreq[T](xs: List[T]): List[T] = {
     |   val freq = collection.mutable.Map.empty[T, Int] withDefaultValue 0
     |   xs foreach (k => freq(k) -= 1)
     |   xs.distinct sortBy freq
     | }
sortByFreq: [T](xs: List[T])List[T]

scala> sortByFreq(keys)
res2: List[String] = List(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

My prefered versions would be:

*Most canonical / expressive?*

```
keys.groupBy(identity).toList.map{ case (k,v) => (-v.size,k)  }.sorted.map(_._2)
```

*Shortest and probably most efficient?*

```
keys.groupBy(identity).toList.sortBy(-_._2.size).map(_._1)
```

*Straight forward*

```
keys.groupBy(identity).values.toList.sortBy(-_.size).map(_.head)
```